# Python Optimize Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, optimization, phantomjs

I've made a scraper for Pinterest that runs properly but is very slow on a good spec hardware.

**Logic**

- User enters url of pins, filename of csv file through arguments
- Start selenium (using phantomjs[ghost driver] latest)
- Scrape data and store in arrays
- Selenium script performs infinite scroll and 'see more' button click to reveal more data about a pin
- Save arrays into pandas dataframe and generate csv

**Problem**
The script runs fine but it's very slow & sometimes it freezez.

**Code - Declerations**

```
import time, argparse, pandas, datetime
from selenium import webdriver

# global lists for data storage
image_links = []
image_titles = []
image_descriptions = []
pin_links = []
pin_Board_Names = []
pin_Author_Names = []
scrape_timestamps = []
```

**Code - makeCSV**

```
def makeCsv(filename):
    # csv head title along with data list for each
    data={"Time Stamps":scrape_timestamps, "Author Names":pin_Author_Names, "Pins Board":pin_Board_Names, "Pin Links":pin_links, "Image URLs":image_links, "Image Titles":image_titles, "Image Descriptions":image_descriptions}

    # create pandas dataframe from above dictionary
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

    # transpose the dataframe - lists data as rows instead of columns in csv
    dataframe = dataframe.transpose()

    # save csv file
    dataframe.to_csv(filename, sep=',')
```

**Code - Grab/Scraping**

```
def grab(url, filename):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='phantomjs.exe')
    print("\n\nGhost Driver Invoked")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # if element not found, wait for (seconds) before next operation
    driver.get(url) # grab the url

    time.sleep(3) # seconds

    # Scrolling till the end of page
    print("Started Scroling ...")
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == 2:
            break
        else:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(5) # seconds
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            print("Scrolled: " + str(new_height))
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height
        i += 1

    time.sleep(3) # seconds

    # Get all pins , number of pins collected
    total_pins = []
    try:
        total_pins = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Grid__Item")
    except:
        print("Unable to load pins")
    print("Total Pins: " + str(len(total_pins)))

    # get number of 'see more' buttons collected - for error checking
    moreButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@data-test-id="seemoretoggle"]')
    print("Dynamic Elements: " + str(len(moreButtons)))
    print("Display: Dynamic Elements ...")

    # clicking all 'See More' buttons
    i = 0
    while i <= (len(moreButtons) - 1):
        moreButtons[i].click()
        print("Clicked: " + str(i+1))
        i += 1

    # Pin Image URLs
    i = 1
    while i < len(total_pins):
        try:

            temp_xpath = "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[1]/a/img"
            temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath).get_attribute("src")
            image_links.append(temp)
            scrape_timestamps.append(str(datetime.datetime.now())) # save timestamps of scrape
            i += 1
        except:
            i += 1
            pass
    print("Total Images: " + str(i))

    # Image Titles
    imageTitle_Elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("PinAttributionTitle__title")
    i = 1
    for imageTitle_Element in imageTitle_Elements:
        image_titles.append(imageTitle_Element.text)
        i += 1
    print("Total Titles: " + str(i))

    # Image Descriptions
    imageDesc_Elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("PinDescription__desc")
    i = 1
    for imageDesc_Element in imageDesc_Elements:
        image_descriptions.append(imageDesc_Element.text)
        i += 1
    print("Total Descriptions: " + str(i))

    # Pin Page Link
    i = 1
    while i < len(total_pins):
        temp_xpath = "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[1]/a"
        temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath).get_attribute("href")
        print("Pin Link:" + str(i))
        pin_links.append(temp)
        i += 1
    print("Total PinLinks: " + str(i))

    # Pin Board Names
    print("Extracting Board Names ... ")
    i = 1
    successful = False # for checking success of try | else not working
    while i <= len(total_pins):
        try:
            temp_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/h4/a[1]"
            temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath)
            pin_Board_Names.append(temp.text)
            print("Board_No: " + str(i) + " > " + temp.text)
            successful = True
        except:
            temp_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[2]/div/h4/a[1]"
            temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath)
            pin_Board_Names.append(temp.text)
            print("Board_No: " + str(i) + " > " + temp.text)
            successful = True
        if successful == False:
            print("Board_No: " + str(i) + " not found!")
        i += 1

    # Pin Author Names
    print("Extracting Author Names ... ")
    i = 1
    successful = False
    while i <= len(total_pins):
        try:
            temp_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/h4/a[2]"
            temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath)
            pin_Author_Names.append(temp.text)
            print("Author_No: " + str(i) + " > " + temp.text)
            successful = True
        except:
            temp_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[" + str(i) + "]/div/div/div[2]/div/h4/a[2]"
            temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(temp_xpath)
            pin_Author_Names.append(temp.text)
            print("Author_No: " + str(i) + " > " + temp.text)
            successful = True
        if successful == False:
            print("Author_No: " + str(i) + " not found!")
        i += 1

    # generate csv from collected items
    makeCsv(filename)

    # quit driver
    driver.quit()
```

**Code - main**

```
def main():
    # start argument parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # custom arguments
    parser.add_argument("-url", "--url", help="Enter the URL")
    parser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname", help="Enter Filename")

    # parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # all web driver functions happen here:
    grab(args.url, args.fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Slow Output**

```
>>> C:\Users\da74\Desktop\sites\pinscraper\ps>python -W ignore scrape.py --url https://www.pinterest.com/vijayakumargana/classic-kuala-lumpur/ --fname classic_kl.csv


Ghost Driver Invoked
Started Scroling ...
Scrolled: 11124
Scrolled: 18388
Total Pins: 126
Dynamic Elements: 125
Display: Dynamic Elements ...
Clicked: 1
Clicked: 2
Clicked: 3
Clicked: 4
Clicked: 5
Clicked: 6
Clicked: 7
Clicked: 8
Clicked: 9
Clicked: 10
Clicked: 11
Clicked: 12
Clicked: 13
Clicked: 14
Clicked: 15
Clicked: 16
Clicked: 17
Clicked: 18
Clicked: 19
Clicked: 20
Clicked: 21
Clicked: 22
Clicked: 23
Clicked: 24
Clicked: 25
Clicked: 26
Clicked: 27
Clicked: 28
Clicked: 29
Clicked: 30
Clicked: 31
Clicked: 32
Clicked: 33
Clicked: 34
Clicked: 35
Clicked: 36
Clicked: 37
Clicked: 38
Clicked: 39
Clicked: 40
Clicked: 41
Clicked: 42
Clicked: 43
Clicked: 44
Clicked: 45
Clicked: 46
Clicked: 47
Clicked: 48
Clicked: 49
Clicked: 50
Clicked: 51
Clicked: 52
Clicked: 53
Clicked: 54
Clicked: 55
Clicked: 56
Clicked: 57
Clicked: 58
Clicked: 59
Clicked: 60
Clicked: 61
Clicked: 62
Clicked: 63
Clicked: 64
Clicked: 65
Clicked: 66
Clicked: 67
Clicked: 68
Clicked: 69
Clicked: 70
Clicked: 71
Clicked: 72
Clicked: 73
Clicked: 74
Clicked: 75
Clicked: 76
Clicked: 77
Clicked: 78
Clicked: 79
Clicked: 80
Clicked: 81
Clicked: 82
Clicked: 83
Clicked: 84
Clicked: 85
Clicked: 86
Clicked: 87
Clicked: 88
Clicked: 89
Clicked: 90
Clicked: 91
Clicked: 92
Clicked: 93
Clicked: 94
Clicked: 95
Clicked: 96
Clicked: 97
Clicked: 98
Clicked: 99
Clicked: 100
Clicked: 101
Clicked: 102
Clicked: 103
Clicked: 104
Clicked: 105
Clicked: 106
Clicked: 107
Clicked: 108
Clicked: 109
Clicked: 110
Clicked: 111
Clicked: 112
Clicked: 113
Clicked: 114
Clicked: 115
Clicked: 116
Clicked: 117
Clicked: 118
Clicked: 119
Clicked: 120
Clicked: 121
Clicked: 122
Clicked: 123
Clicked: 124
Clicked: 125
```

The script freezez after clicking all js buttons. Even when it's clicking the buttons, it slows down a lot. Using Python3.6, Windows 10 x64 Professional, 8GB RAM, 2TB HDD.

If anyone can help and suggest ways to optimize it and stop it from freezing when too many things or larger pages?
Thankyou.

Comment: Why not use `scrapy`?

Comment: if the response time of the site is slow, then irrespective of the hardware, your script will be slow

Comment: There is an entire SE called https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for these situations I think (Not sure if yours will fit better there).

Comment: @bigbounty I waited for 4 hours just for reading 120 pins.. and Pinterest is responding fast.. also not blocked because using selenium.

Comment: Then check with your proxy or VPN provider. If the server of VPN is slow, then your script also will be running slow

Comment: @bigbounty | needs docker, needs splash(which isn't working for me despite reporting on github repo)..

Comment: @bigbounty And selenium should work anyway. It's the same thing.. using a js enabled web driver to load pages.. selenium got more support & usable with any language without docker & other dependencies.

Comment: @bigbounty Not using server. Localhost, not network issue. Site response time fast, not much cpu load, not much memory used.. But I guess it's about reading too much html data at once? Idk, but I guess optimization issue.

Comment: See if the links you scrape have redirects. This might also slow your script execution

Comment: Why not try to record the time spent at each step to spot where is the script spending most of the time?